# Rotate images evenly

Tags: php

I have X number of images but only space to display one at a time on my homepage.

I'd like to rotate them but not in a slideshow manner, instead on refresh.

So with every page load, a different image should load. I can do it randomly but is there a way to evenly rotate them? to avoid the same image potentially displaying multiple times in a row.

I'm guessing there is no way to do this without tracking/checking views in a db? that said, it doesn't need to be perfect, just reasonably evenly distributed.

Comment: Do you want the images to display randomly but preventing 2 equal results in a row, or just show the images in order from first to last?

Comment: randomly but prevent two in a row

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use sessions to initially assign the images in a random order.. and keep track of the last image offset.

```
session_start();
$images = ['/img1.jpg','/img2.jpg']; // <-- Define your images here
if (!isset($_SESSION["images"])){
     shuffle($images);
     $_SESSION["images"] = $images;
     $_SESSION["current_image"] = 0;
} else {
     $_SESSION["current_image"]++;
}
$next_offset = $_SESSION["current_image"]%count($_SESSION["images"]);
$featured_image = $_SESSION["images"][$next_offset];
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't really think of sessions. That's a good solution as I didn't want to use a database in this instance.

Comment: I guess this will work for evenly swapping after the first is shown but the first load will still need to be random. So what could be added is tracking views on each ad and when the page/session is first loaded, it shows the one with the lease views first?

Comment: if not seeded the list gets seeded with the shuffled array so the the random order is established prior to serving up the first one. adding tracking should be trivial.